# StreamWriter Replace while Writing to a new Text File

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter

Is there any possible way to replace a character with a string, like to say replace `'\x0A'` with `"\r\n"` for example. This is my code and I honestly can't find a way to put it in, not to mention that the `Replace` function does not allow `String.Replace(Char, String)` or `String.Replace(String, Char)`

```
StreamWriter wwrite = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("EUC-JP"));
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    wwrite.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString() + "＾" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
}
wwrite.Close();
```

Comment: Which string, in your example, contains the characters that you want to replace?

Comment: Some of the items on the listView1 contains the line return.

Comment: didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: Please explain what didn't work.  What did you try.  What were the expected results and what were the actual results?

Comment: alright here is what i tried: wwrite.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString() + "＾" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text.Replace(('\x0A').ToString, "\n")), i exported the whole listview as a text file, it should outcome all the strings that have a line return or new line as a single line, and instead of those line returns, the string "\n" would apear.

Comment: In that code, you are replacing '\x0A' with "\n".  But \n *is* \x0A, so the replace will have no effect.  If you want to remove the new lines, replace it with an empty string.

Comment: i think '\n' is '\x0A', not "\n", since "\n" is the string (\n), while '\n' is the character Escape for a new line, well i think. I also tried replacing System.Environment.NewLine but no use :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37342/discussion-between-omarrrio-and-steven-doggart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace a character with a string by simply converting the character to a string and then calling the `Replace(string, string)` overload.  For instance:

```
wwrite.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString() + "＾" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text.Replace("\x0A", "\r\n"));
```

You seem to be confused about strings.  Strings are simply a collection of characters.  So `"\n"` and `'\n'` are essentially the same value.  The first stores the value as a single character string and the second stores the same value as a character.  If you want to replace a new-line character with the actual string `\n` (as two separate characters), you need to escape the backslash, for instance:

```
s = s.Replace("\n", "\\n");
```

Or:

```
s = s.Replace("\n", @"\n");
```